# Counter part for snipping tool in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: screenshot

Can you please tell me the screenshot tool in Ubuntu 16.04 which could be as similar as Snipping tool in Windows.

Answer (score 2):

The standard preinstalled screenshot tool is `gnome-screenshot`, it listens on the <kbd>PrntScr</kbd> key of your keyboard.

An extensive screenshot tool you can install additionally is `shutter`.